# op amp circuit electrical enginnering tutorial question about amplifier op amp circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX09ZR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

I answer for part b is V2=(R2+R3/R1+R2+R3)*(+Vin=+15V)..it will gives you a 10V..
I answer for part C is v1=(R2+R3/R1+R2+R3)*(+15v)..it will gives you a 10v..

i still in doubt..when the time i'm reading for part b answer..they stated that 5V less than Vin less than 10V...if i applying like this for part b and c with a same working step,it okay with it?

Comment: R1 R2 and R3 are 1k Ohm each...

Comment: The opamps are being used as voltage comparators in that circuit, so don't use the gain formula. The outputs are either high (14v) or low (2v).

Comment: Please consider reformatting and actually stating a question in a readable format (text). What have you tried, what is the specific part you don't understand.

Comment: i using Vout=-(Rf/Ri)Vin formula but i've got the -5V for a,i've got a -10 V for Part B and i've got the -10v for part c..what's the meaning of less than 5 v,10 and for the part b-5 vs is less than Vin and less than 10V?can i have your work out solutions?thanks..

Comment: There is no feedback in those op amp circuits - neither Vo1 or Vo2 are going back to the inputs, so you cannot use a formula based on feedback.

Comment: @RyanPhway - there is no feedback resistor, so there is no meaningful value for Rf in that formula.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 555 input stage. The amplifiers are used as comparators. Their output will be either VOUTMAX or VOUTMIN, VOUTMAX being the supply minus the upper saturation voltage, VOUTMIN being the ground plus the lower saturation voltage. According to the text, VOUTMAX is 14V and VOUTMIN is 2V.

The output of each comparator is VOUTMAX if the + input is above the - input and VOUTMIN if the + input is lower than the - input.

Now you can just look at the Vin signal and compare with the - input of each comparator to get your answer.

[Edit] With VDD is 15 V:

- voltage between R3 and R2: V3 = (R3)/(R1+R2+R3) * VDD = 5 V
- voltage between R2 and R1: V2 = (R2+R3)/(R1+R2+R3) * VDD = 10 V

Comment: R1 R2 R3 can becomes a 3 k ohm?do i need to make a short circuit to R2 and R3?it will gives me 2 khohms...

Comment: R1, R2, R3 make a resistive divider. The negative input of the comparators are therefore 5 V and 10 V.

Comment: what kind of formula can gives me an answer and how to get a -5v for a,for part b and -10v for part c..is that possible to use this Vref=R2/R1+R2 (+V)??

Comment: V3 = (R3)/(R1+R2+R3) * VDD, V2 = (R2+R3)/(R1+R2+R3) * VDD, where VDD is 15 V.

Comment: what is the meaning of b answer 5V is less than Vin and less than 10V?why do they write like this?i've got the answer for part a b and c..thanks mac..thank you bro...

Comment: for the part b is said that 5V is less than Vin and vin is less than 10v..5 v less than Vin less than 10v..the answer was said it but i've already got an answer for a and c..how do i know these voltages are less than Vin at part b..

Comment: are these working step for part b and c are the same workout?

Comment: i was using the formula,V2=(R2+R3/R1+R2+R3)multiply with (+15V) VDD..I've got an answer for 10v for part b and c but what's the meaning of part b answer is stated that 5V is less than Vin and less than 10V?while i solving the part b and c,i using the same working step and same formula,(R2+R3/R1+R2+R3)multiply with an VDD +15v..I've got an answer 10v respectively for it...

Comment: Answer B is worded in a confusing way.  I would say "Vin is between 5 V and 10 V".  Likewise, C should be "Vin is greater than 10 V".

Comment: @Ryan, you didn't copy my formulas correctly. Look at the parenthesis.